# Does standard search index against content file body

Tags: files, search, content, body

I cannot find any documentation regarding if Standard Salesforce search performs the search against File Content, for example, if I have a PDF document with content 'ask my anything' or 'hallucinating', and upload that PDF file to the Salesforce, and then try to search it in Salesforce search in the internal organization as well as in the Experience Cloud search, would it be searchable?

Answer (score 1):

Still wasn't able to find the documentation, but was able to get a result by method of trial.

[image]

However, there is some delay before the search result is available.

Also, the search results are available in Experience Cloud portal search.

[image]